# Conflict in asp.net mvc3 routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am using asp.net mvc3 and have two different type of request in same controller and i am facing error in accesing the correct method

**Firstcondition**

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        "Tag1", // Route name
        "Tag/{no}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Tag", action = "TagCloud", no = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

In this case user will access `Tag Controller` like this `http://xyz.com/tag` **OR** `http://xyz.com/tag/3` where number is actually page number

**Secondcondition**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           "Tag", // Route name
           "Tag/{tag}/{page}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Tag", action = "Index", tag = "tag", page = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

In this case user must give a name of tag in order to get detail page of that tag like this `http://xyz.com/tag/mvc` where `mvc` is the name of tag **OR** `http://xyz.com/tag/mvc/3` where `mvc` is tag name and `3` is page no which is optional ,

now problem is that both are not working at same time , anyone which is on the top runs , and mvc skip the lower one . Please help and thanks in advance .

Comment: Try to change its order, means write the second one before first or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Tag", // Route name
   "Tag/{tag}/{page}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Tag", action = "Index", tag = "tag", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
   new { page = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   "Tag1", // Route name
   "Tag/{no}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Tag", action = "TagCloud", no = UrlParameter.Optional },
   new { no = @"\d+" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the order of the two route definition? Add constraint to the first one {no} part: have to be number, if not present be 0.

Comment: first one runs and mvc skip the other one

Comment: all request gone to first one

Comment: i am checking number in my code weather its null or not . So i think thats not a problem

Comment: But the routing engine will not execute the first rule on request like http://xyz.com/tag/mvc or http://xyz.com/tag/mvc/3 ("mvc" is not a number). Give it a try.

Comment: no man !!! its not working its using the first route ?  what you think what should be the problem